# How to fix try except error on inventory program?

Tags: python

I have an inventory program that 100% works and I need it to never error out. To prevent this I have made CHOICE default to display a message and reshow the menu. I believe I have the program try / except correct, but I now no matter what you enter it displays the error message. How did I fix this? If you have any questions please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Full Code:

```
import os


name = []

qty = []

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name, qty):
        self.name = name
        self.qty = qty


def menuDisplay():
    print ('=============================')
    print ('= Inventory Management Menu =')
    print ('=============================')
    print ('(1) Add New Item to Inventory')
    print ('(2) Remove Item from Inventory')
    print ('(3) Update Inventory')
    print ('(4) Search Item in Inventory')
    print ('(5) Print Inventory Report')
    print ('(99) Quit')
    while 1:
        try:
            CHOICE = int(input("Enter choice: "))
            menuDisplay(CHOICE)
            if CHOICE == 1:
                while 1:
                    print('Adding Inventory')
                    print('================')
                    new_name = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
                    name.append(new_name)
                    new_qty = int(input("Enter the quantity of the item: "))
                    qty.append(new_qty)
                    CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
                if CHOICE == 98:
                    menuDisplay()
                elif CHOICE == 99:
                    exit()
                elif CHOICE == 2:
                    print('Removing Inventory')
                    print('==================')
                    removing = input('Enter the item name to remove from inventory: ')
                    indexdel = name.index(removing)
                    name.pop(indexdel)
                    qty.pop(indexdel)
                    CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
                if CHOICE == 98:
                    menuDisplay()
                elif CHOICE == 99:
                    exit()
                elif CHOICE == 3:
                    print('Updating Inventory')
                    print('==================')
                    item = input('Enter the item to update: ')
                    update = int(input("Enter the updated quantity. Enter 5 for additional or -5 for less: "))
                    if update >= 0:
                        qty[name.index(item)] += update
                        print("Update made")
                        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
                        if CHOICE == 98:
                            menuDisplay()
                        elif CHOICE == 99:
                            exit()
                    elif update <= -1:
                        qty[name.index(item)] += update
                        print("Update Made")
                        CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
                        if CHOICE == 98:
                            menuDisplay()
                        elif CHOICE == 99:
                            exit()
                elif CHOICE == 4:
                    print('Searching Inventory')
                    print('===================')
                    search = input('Enter the name of the item: ')
                    pos = name.index(search) if search in name else -1
                    if (pos >= 0):
                        print ('Item:     ', name[pos])
                        print ('Quantity: ', qty[pos])
                        print ('----------')
                    else:
                        print("Item not in inventory")
                    CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
                    if CHOICE == 98:
                        menuDisplay()
                    elif CHOICE == 99:
                        exit()
                elif CHOICE == 5:
                    print('Current Inventory')
                    print('=================')
                    zipo = list(zip(name, qty))
                    for foobar in zipo:
                        print("Item : ",foobar[0], "\nQuantity : ",foobar[1])
                        print('----------')
                    CHOICE = int(input('Enter 98 to continue or 99 to exit: '))
                if CHOICE == 98:
                    menuDisplay()
                elif CHOICE == 99:
                    exit()
                else:
                    print("Please enter a number between 1 and 5")
                    menuDisplay()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Invalid choice! try again!"+str(e))

menuDisplay()
```

Comment: Heard of [Fuzz Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing)? There's something called [pythonfuzz](https://github.com/fuzzitdev/pythonfuzz) that could do what you want.

Comment: it has to be in code not a downloaded extra

Comment: Do you understand why I suggested that? It's for testing your code and making changes to it, you don't actually include this with your final code.

Comment: Looks like wrong indentation. Move everything from `elif CHOICE == 2` up to `except ... ` 4 spaces left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could solve this with a try, except?

```
x = input("enter digit: ")
try:
    x = int(x)
except ValueError:
    print(f"{x} is not an Integer")
    # Handle error in input 

print(x)
```

Comment: I think I figured it out, can you please take a look at the current issue?

Comment: You are trying to pass an argument to `menuDisplay()` while the function takes no arguments. Try commenting this line out.

Comment: which line are referencing?

Comment: @user14391204 at line 27